# Why does division in Java displayonly 0?

Tags: java, casting, operators

I have the following method in a Java program:

```
public void Div(int a, int b){
            //exception in order to check if the second argument is 0
            try{
                int div1 = (a / b);
                double div = div1;
                System.out.println("The division of the two numbers is: " + div);
            }
            catch(ArithmeticException e){
                System.out.println("You can't divide a number by 0");
            }
```

This only works if numerator is larger than the denominator ( e.g 8/2). If the numerator is smaller than the denominator I get a result of 0.0 (e.g. 2/8).

What can I do to make it work?

Comment: use other datatypes then int. int are only whole numbers, no decimals. change a, b and div1 into float or double

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's happening because of integer division. You can cast one of the arguments to `double` and store the result to a `double` variable to fix the issue.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        div(5, 10);
    }

    public static void div(int a, int b) {
        try {
            double div = (double) a / b;
            System.out.println("The division of the two numbers is: " + div);
        } catch (ArithmeticException e) {
            System.out.println("You can't divide a number by 0");
        }
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The division of the two numbers is: 0.5
```

On a side note, you should follow [Java naming conventions](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html) e.g. the method name, `Div` should be `div` as per the Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

`(a/b)` You're doing integer division. You need to typecast to other data types that can store decimal like `double`.

```
 double div = (double) a / b;
```